# Kali Linux MAC address changing on MacBook Pro Retina

Tags: network, command-line, unix

Apparently this could be due to my hardware said one stack exchanger.

Anyway, for your information:

```
root@kali:~# lspci | grep Wireless
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
```

That is my wlan0 and for some reason if I try to change it I get these errors:

```
root@kali:~# macchanger -a wlan0                                                                                                                              
Current MAC:   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (Apple)
Permanent MAC: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (Apple)
[ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Too many open files in system
```

or

```
root@kali:~# ifconfig wlan0 down
root@kali:~# ifconfig wlan0 hw ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
SIOCSIFHWADDR: Too many open files in system
```

Does it mean that I have got to blacklist/remove the additional drivers that I downloaded but aren't using?

Comment: [How to install Broadcom BCM4360 on debian on Macbook pro](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175810/how-to-install-broadcom-bcm4360-on-debian-on-macbook-pro)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried taking the interface down, then running '**macchanger**' and see if it takes?

I had a friend a while back who was way into *Kali*, she'd actually used *Backtrack* for a while but she was definitely on the "ethical hacking" bent. It was sort of mind-boggling watching her pull open drawer after drawer of tightly choreographed penetration testing kits, all sorted by app type & conveniently available for rapid deployment.

I scripted '**macchanger**' & related wifi maintenence commands into a single monolithic shell file & helped her install it under /usr/local/sbin/mace - I think we called it '**mace**' as in "**MAC-E**raser", but she was in charge from then on for resetting the damned router, so eventually we ended up joking that "...oh, Katelynne? Yeah, uh... she's outside right now macing the Comcast guy.

( My friends & I are easily amused. )